# watchOS app's icon is blank on the Watch app on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, icons, assets, watchos-4

I recently created a WatchKit extension of my iOS app. Xcode created 2 new targets:

`WatchOS Target`
`WatchOS Extension`

Each of these target has its own `Assets.xcassets` file. I've included the proper icons with the correct dimensions to both of these files, but the app icon is still showing blank on the Watch app on iPhone like so:
[image]

The icon is showing properly on my Watch. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

"Each of these target has its own Assets.xcassets file. I've included the proper icons with the correct dimensions to both of these files, but the app icon is still showing blank on the Watch app on iPhone like so: "

Do you have the Apple Watch app icons in your iPhone asset catalog?  There are several included on the iPhone side.

Comment: It will help the question if you list which ones you added on the phone side.  I suspect you have missed an important one.  Also, removing the app from the phone and re-installing may cause them to show up.  Sometimes it seems the caches are not properly updated.